# Check if layer is a marker when using Leaflet's eachLayer

Tags: leaflet

I would like to use Leaflet's *map.eachLayer(...)* to do something to every **marker** in the map. I am not sure how to detect markers, however.

Is there a way to find out of what class the current layer is an instance of?

I guess I could add a custom property to each marker that I create, such as:

```
L.marker([40.49083 , -108.95966], {layerType: 'marker'}).addTo(map);
```

And then check if that property exists... but maybe there is a more elegant way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the answer to similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18014907/leaflet-draw-retrieve-layer-type-on-drawedited-event one possible solution would be:

```
map.eachLayer(function (layer) {
    if (layer instanceof L.Marker){
        //Do marker specific actions here
    }
});
```

Comment: Any feedback? Elegant enough?

Comment: I did something along these lines, using instanceof, but apparently I missed something... [check]